# access to ipod library for streaming over upnp

Tags: ios, itunes, media, upnp

I am implementing an app who should be able to stream music from ipad/iphone to a specific device over upnp. my app should be media server and control point.

i am using Platinum SDK and i managed to access itunes library from mac, but not from ipad/iphone

Any ideas about how can i make available the itunes library?